# iOS - TensorFlow Lite Error: Select TensorFlow op(s), included in the given model is(are) not supported by this interpreter

Tags: ios, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to integrate on-device machine learning using react-native. I have converted a transformers model from huggingface to a tensorflow lite file. Doing so, I can get the model to successfully run on the android side of things. When I try to do the same for iOS I am getting this following error:

`TensorFlow Lite Error: Select TensorFlow op(s), included in the given model is(are) not supported by this interpreter. Make sure you apply/link Flex delegate before inference. For the Android, it can be resolved by adding "org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops" dependency.`

`TensorFlow Lite Error: Node number 95 (FlexErf) failed to prepare.`

I had a similar error on the android side and I solved it using the guide here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select

I have followed the steps on the above link for iOS as well and yet I am still getting this error:
This includes:

- Adding the dependency in the podfile
- Running pod install
- Adding the other flag links in the build settings.

How can I get past this error?

Comment: were you able to resolve this? experiencing same issue ...

Answer (score 0):

are you following the instruction [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select#ios)? Are you building for armv7 or arm64? armv7 is no longer supported in latest nightly builds and the [latest nightly builds](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/tree/master/Specs/3/f/8/TensorFlowLiteSelectTfOps/0.0.1-nightly.20220601) distribute xcframeworks now. So when you `-force_load` the framework, you might need to do `-force_load $(SRCROOT)/Pods/TensorFlowLiteSelectTfOps/Frameworks/TensorFlowLiteSelectTfOps.xcframework/ios-arm64/TensorFlowLiteSelectTfOps.framework/TensorFlowLiteSelectTfOps`